# How to prevent mysql protocol 41 client authentication bypass attempt alert

Tags: mysql, database, protocols, alert, firewall

I am getting mysql protocol 41 client authentication bypass attempt alert on firewall.

May anyone tell me that how to prevent it.

Comment: by disabling the alert. If its blocked by do you need an alert?

Comment: Hi @danblack,  is there any security issues or it is a normal alert massage?

Comment: if its blocked there's no issues. Was it from inside or outside your network? If inside maybe you need to look, if its outside its just the noise of persistent scanners for vulnerabilities that can be ignored (hence disable the alert). Also as this isn;t a programming question it belongs on a different site maybe serverfault.com/